# " Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" in angular drag n drop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use angular drag and drop http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop, but when I am trying a basic example, i am getting the error. My code -

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <style>
        table, th , td  {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <html  ng-app="myApp">
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <div ng-controller="dragDropController">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                  <div class="btn btn-primary" data-drag="true" ng-model="list" jqyoui-draggable="{animate: true}">{{list.title}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                  <div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" ng-model="droppedList" jqyoui-droppable="{beforeDrop: 'beforeDrop'}"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{!$Resource.AngularDragDrop}" />
        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', ['ngDragDrop']).controller('dragDropController', function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.list = {title : 'Drag me..!!'}
                $scope.droppedList = {title: 'Drop place'};
                $scope.beforeDrop = function() {
                    console.log('Before dropping..!!');
                };
            });

        </script>
    </html>

</apex:page>
```

Can someone help me with same.??
I have tried using same different versions of angular and also tried copying angular version from the actual site example but still facing same error

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: `<script src="{!$Resource.AngularDragDrop}" />` script tag cannot be self-closed

Comment: THis was not the issue

Comment: This _is_ one of the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `beforeDrop` function should **return a promise** ([documentation](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/)).

The plugin executes your `beforeDrop`, where you would typically ask the user for confirmation, and **then** it "drops" (or not).

As you are not waiting for user input, to get rid of the error you could inject `$q` and return the dummiest promise, so to speak:

```
$scope.beforeDrop = function () {
    console.log('Before dropping..!!');
    return $q.when();
}
```

But the final look of `beforeDrop` will be more like:

```
$scope.beforeDrop = function () {
    // open modal
    // ...
    return modalPromise;
}
```